# Inflationärer, meist falscher Gebrauch von "Konnotation"

Tags: discussion

Laut Tag-Wiki handelt es sich bei einer Konnotation um Folgendes:

> An additional, not immediately obvious meaning or association attached
>   to the main meaning of a word or phrase. Connotations can be
>   reflections of specific cultural or historical context, thinking
>   patterns, value judgements, etc. In German: die Konnotation / die
>   Nebenbedeutung.

Mir stoßen immer wieder Antworten auf, die einem Begriff eine Wertung zuordnen, die bei analytischer Betrachtung gar nicht an diesem hängt, sondern nur an dessen häufigstem Gebrauch.

Beispielsweise behauptet Jan [hier](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/31148/266), dass schlank eine positive Konnotation hätte. Zwar wird das Wort, wenn es wertend für Personen gebraucht wird, meist positiv verwendet. Man kann sich aber leicht klar machen, dass sich dies nur aus dem Kontext und nicht aus dem Wort ergibt - etwa kann die Täterbeschreibung der Polizei einen schlanken Täter beschreiben und ist sicher nicht wertend gemeint.

Außerdem ist es keine Nebenbedeutung des Wortes.

Ähnlich im gleichen Beitrag das *Mager*, wie es aus Magermilch und Magerquark bekannt ist. Das soll eine negative Konnotation haben. Als Gegenteil von *fett* ist da aber keine Nebenbedeutung versteckt. Es ist die Hauptbedeutung, die entweder positiv oder negativ bewertet wird.

"Die Abschiebeversuche der Bundesregierung erzielten nur magere Erfolge."

Kann man hier am Wort mager ablesen, ob der Autor sich mehr Erfolge wünscht? Ich behaupte nein; die Unterstellung, Wörter meinten etwas positivis oder negatives wird meist zu leichtfertig getroffen und hält einer sachlichen Überprüfung selten stand. Man könnte allenfalls davon reden, dass ein Wort häufiger in positiv wertendem Kontext verwendet wird als in negativem, aber wenn man dann analysiert, worin der Unterschied besteht, kommt man nicht umhin festzustellen, dass es jeweils der Kontext ist und nicht das Wort.

Die interne Suche führt, Stand heute, für Konnotation [50 Treffer](https://german.stackexchange.com/search?tab=relevance&pagesize=50&q=konnotation) auf, für die englische Entsprechung connotation stolze [429 Treffer](https://german.stackexchange.com/search?q=connotation).

Es nervt mich immer die gleichen Rückfragen zu stellen:

- Ist es wirklich eine Nebenbedeutung?
- Hängt die Bewertung am Wort oder hängt sie am Kontext?

Ein weiteres Beispiel für die vergebliche Suche nach Nebenbedeutungen wäre die Frage nach einem möglichen Wandel in der Nebenbedeutung von [emsig](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/3763/266) durch das Forenschwergewicht Takkat.

Emsig heißt nun mal *fleißig*, nicht *begabt* oder *genial*. Der ironische Unterton ergibt sich wieder aus dem Kontext, wie auch eine Wortersetzung zeigt, die man vornehmen kann, ohne den Texten eine andere Note zu verleihen. Ironische Untertöne kann man allen Eigenschaftswörtern verleihen, soweit ich weiß.

Deswegen ist die Beschäftigung mit [Konnationen](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Konnotation) meist nichts weiter als Rauschen, so als beschäftige man sich bei jedem Substantiv mit den Unterschieden von bestimmtem und unbestimmtem Artikel (der Bär, ein Bär).

Auch [blauäugig](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/3595/266) ist m.E. kein gutes Beispiel für eine Nebenbedeutung, sondern es ist schlicht eine Metapher.

Die Frage ob [Mischling](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/15251/266) eine negative Konnotation hat ist bei kurzer Suche eine der wenigen, die mir sinnvoll erscheint. Das Wort selbst, wenn man dessen Geschichte nicht kennt, müsste nicht abwertend sein. Eine Metapher ist es auch nicht. Theoretisch wäre eine Gesellschaft denkbar, in der man über die Abstammung der Personen spricht, ohne dabei zu werten, und in der dieser Begriff ein taugliches Instrument wäre. Aber die Konnotationen haben ihn vergiftet. Hier finde ich **Konnotation** angemessen.

Comment: Und nun?                            ..............

Comment: Aber bei _Mischling_ hängt es doch auch vom Kontext ab. Denk an Hunde! Da hat es sogar oftmals eine positive Nebenbedeutung und man assoziiert einen Mischlingshund gern mit einem fröhlichen und ungewöhnlich (lustig) aussehenden Hund. Ich denke die Konnotation hängt _immer_ vom Kontext ab und gerade die mehrheitliche Verwendung eines Begriffes _in_ einem gewissen Kontext gibt ihm die Nebenbedeutung. Oder habe ich dich missverstanden?

Comment: @PerlDog: Ist die mehrheitliche Bedeutung nicht die Hauptbedeutung? Zu Mischling: Ich weiß nicht, welche Verwendung ursprünglich mal dominant war. ich kenne Mischling noch aus meiner Jugend, Indianerliteratur. Da bietet sich die Figur entweder als Vermittler an, weil 2 Völkern verbunden, oder als Verräter. Für Personen im Alltag wurde der Begriff aber nie gebraucht. Eine Nebenbedeutung "Hund" ist aber auch dann nicht gegeben. "Billig" hat m.M.n. eine Konnotation von "Ramsch". "Die Partei" von SED und NSDAP.

Comment: Ich will hier gar nicht in Frage stellen, dass Konnotation manchmal falsch verwendet wird. Aber deine Messlatte ist offensichtlich falsch. Ja, "schlank" ist positiv konnotiert, und "mager" negativ. Das merkst du nicht daran, dass erst diese Konnotation den Kontext negativ dastehen lässt, wie du zu meinen scheinst, sondern daran, dass du gerade das positiv konnotierte Wort viel lieber in einem positiven Kontext und das negativ konnotierte in einem negativen Kontext verwenden würdest. "Die Abschiebeversuche der Bundesregierung erzielten nur schlanke Erfolge" ist total seltsam, und wenn die ...

Comment: ... Polizei mich als mageren Täter bezeichnen würde, wäre ich schon ein bisschen beleidigt.

Comment: @sgf: Ich kaufe ein mageres Stück Fleisch. Daran ist nichts negativ, im Ggt. Oder Magerquark - würden die Hersteller kaum draufdrucken, wenn es neg. bewertet würde.

Comment: Wenn ich "mageres Fleisch" google, hat der zweite Link in der Beschreibung "Mageres Fleisch ist trocken und fad? Von wegen!" Scheint also auch nicht gerade positiv zu sein. (Womöglich in Wahrheit schon, aber die Emotion, die man damit verbindet, nicht, und darauf kommt es bei der Konnotation ja wohl an.) Aber mein Punkt  ist ja eigentlich der: Nur weil ein Wort positiv konnotiert ist, muss ja nicht jeder Kontext, in dem es vorkommt, positiv sein. Aber ob ich jemanden oder etwas als "mager" oder "schlank" bezeichne, macht eindeutig einen Unterschied dahingehend aus, ob die Eigenschaft selbst...

Comment: ... als positiv oder negativ aufgefasst wird. Gerade bei "schlanker Täter" vs "magerer Täter" vs "dünner Täter" scheint mir das ganz eindeutig positiv vs. negativ vs. neutral zu sein. Und genau das ist dann die nebenbedeutung, die Hauptbedeutung ist ja in allen Fällen dieselbe. Dass jetzt "mager" noch eine spezifische andere Verwendung in der Beschreibung von fettarmen Speisen hat, hat damit recht wenig zu tun.

Comment: @sgf: Also der zweite Link (von 20 auf der Seite, oder hast Du nur bis zum zweiten oder überhaupt nur den zweiten beachtet) scheint nicht gerade positiv, sagst Du? Sondern negativ, oder sondern neutral? Aber in Wahrheit doch? Weil da steht ja "von wegen!". Aber damit sind wir erst beim Schein angekommen, der ja bekanntlich oft trügt. Die Emotion soll sich dazu in einem Gegensatz befinden. Wie ist das möglich? Der eine freut sich über mageres Fleisch, weil er nicht dick werden will, der andere nicht, weil er meint, das fettes Fleisch besser mundet. Das sind unterschiedliche Prioritäten, nichts…

Comment: @sgf …was Du dem Wort anheften kannst. Jedes andere Wort, das den Fettgehalt ausdrückt, wird bei dem einen Sorge und dem anderen Freude auslösen. Ein dickes Steak kann auch mager sein - von schlanken Steaks habe ich noch nichts gehört, das sagt man nicht. Magerer Täter habe ich auch noch nie gehört oder gelesen. Die Hauptbedeutung von Schlank und mager ist eben nicht diesselbe. Eine magere Ernte kann man einfahren, eine schlanke nicht. Ein dünnes Steak gibt es schon, das kann aber wiederum fett sein. Wenn Du hungrig bist, wirst Du das positiv sehen, wenn auf Diät negativ. Das macht die Worte …

Comment: @sgf … fett und mager aber nicht zu positiven oder negativen Worten. Bei "fettarmen" Speisen ist die Bedeutung von "mager" keine andere - wie kommst Du darauf? Eine Speise ist wenig fett, ein Täter ist wenig fett, eine Ernte ist wenig fett. Das ist immer die gleiche Hauptbedeutung. Und dann sind da Bewertungen - nicht Nebenbedeutungen. Die können auseinander gehen, abhängig vom Kontext und den Motiven der Sprecher/Hörer bzw. Schreiber/Leser.

Comment: @userunknown Aber wenn mager "nicht fett" und schlank "nicht dick" heißt, warum ist dann mager bei Personen negativ und schlank positiv? Und Konnotation ist (laut dem von dir verlinkten Wikipediaartikel) das, was "die stilistischen, emotionalen, affektiven Wortbedeutungskomponenten enthält – also das, was bei der Verwendung eines Begriffs bewusst oder unbewusst noch mitschwingt" Was verstehst du denn genau unter einer Nebenbedeutung?

Comment: Ich gehe bei Deiner Prämisse schon nicht mit, dass mager bei Personen negativ und schlank positiv sei. Das ist eine Wertung die der Sprecher und/oder Hörer teilen mag oder nicht. Es ist nicht ans Wort gebunden, sondern an die Vorstellungen der Person und an diese nur lose, mag sich im Laufe der Zeit oder von Kontext zu Kontext ändern.

Answer (score 3):

Wenn ich ein Wort, in diesem Fall *Konnotation*, in eklatanter Unkenntnis seiner Bedeutungsnuancen falsch verwende, möchte ich dich hiermit ermutigen, den Fehler mit einem Edit zu beheben und mich in einem Kommentar über meine Fehleinschätzung aufzuklären.

Im Übrigen war mir nicht bewusst, dass du mit deinem Kommentar auf besagte Frage darauf abgezielt hast.

Comment: Nun ja. Diese Antwort kommt mir mehr wie ein Kommentar als wie eine Antwort vor. Wenn Du nach Lesen meines Beitrags nicht der Meinung bist, dass Konnotation das falsche Wort ist, was ich der Tatsache entnehme, dass Du den Beitrag nicht dahingehend geändert hast, dann wäre es offenkundig falsch und übergriffig gewesen Deinen Beitrag in meinem Sinne zu ändern. Edits sollen immer im Sinne des Autors sein. Und da die für mich befremdliche Verwendung von Konnotation so häufig ist halte ich eine Metadiskussion für den richtigen Weg, hoffend ich kann überzeugen oder jemand mich, dass ich Unrecht hab.

Comment: @userunknown Nicht ganz, es ist eher so, dass für mich die ganze Sache nicht wichtig genug ist, als dass ich sofortigen Handlungsbedarf sehe. Und dass ich nicht an diesem exakten Wortlaut hänge. Ich halte es durchaus für möglich, dass ich einem falschen Freund aufsitze, oder dass ich das Wort falsch verwende, weil ich mir nie die Mühe gemacht habe, es nachzuschlagen.

Comment: @userunknown Ich verändere häufiger schon mal den Wortlaut in Antworten. Normalerweise sind das Antworten von Nichtmuttersprachlern, die eben in der Wortwahl offensichtlich daneben gegriffen haben. Aber auch Muttersprachlern passiert dies. Manchmal fehlt einem auch im besagten Moment das richtige Wort oder man hat eigentlich einen anderen Gedanken gehabt und korrigert sich, aber übersieht dann das falsche Wort. Und was weiß ich. "Konnotation" ist schon ein Wort höheren Registers und somit ist Fehlverwendung potentiell möglich. Ich denke, sowas kann man einfach korrigieren....

Comment: ...Oder man weist in klarem Deutsch OP drauf hin, dass man glaubt, dass heir eine Fehlverwendung vorliegt und gerade User wie Jan sind ja bekannt, hier dann auch ggf zu korrigieren oder zu vertreten, warum sie der Meinung sind, dass das gewählte Wort doch richtig ist.

Answer (score 0):

> Beispielsweise behauptet Jan hier, dass *schlank* eine positive Konnotation hätte.

ja naja, es dürfte leicht sein, "schön schlank" zu googlen. Das ist der einfachste Fall einer Con-Notation im Sinne von *con-* (= "mit", "zu-", "ge-"). Zwar ist *notatio* durchaus weiter gefasst als nur auf das schreiben bezogen. Doch solange wir uns hier ausschließlich durch Textmedien austauschen, führt an dieser Auslegung kaum ein Weg vorbei, außer eine der vielen zusätzlichen Bedeutungen von *com-* oder sture ignoranz.

> Zwar wird das Wort, wenn es wertend für Personen gebraucht wird, meist positiv verwendet. Man kann sich aber leicht klar machen, dass sich dies nur aus dem Kontext und nicht aus dem Wort ergibt - etwa kann die Täterbeschreibung der Polizei einen schlanken Täter beschreiben und ist sicher nicht wertend gemeint.

Sehr unpassendes Beispiel. Die Staatsbeamten sind inzwischen zu politisch korrekter Sprache verpflichtet, und zwar genau weil man einem Wort wie einer Person die Bedeutung usw. nicht unbedingt *ex fronte* ansieht. Dennoch sprechen Gerichte gerne von hohem Ansehen. Soll nochmal einer von Grammar-Police sprechen. Ach so, ja verstehe, kein Englisch, also die Grammatik-Faschos.

Übrigens sprichst du damit einen Punkt an, der aber vielleicht doch richtig ist. Darüber bin ich unsicher, was *Morphonotactics* (?) und so angeht, aber im wesentlichen kommt durch den Ausdruck, "Konnotation", vielleicht ein Konzept zum, eh, Ausdruck, das im englischen Sprachraum viel wichtiger ist. Dann spricht man eigentlich von "constituent", glaube ich, also wenn z.B. *sports car* als zwei Worte betrachtet werden, *Sportwagen* aber als eins, oder ebenso *euer Ehren* einmal als floskelhaften Titel, ehemals vielleicht eher als Genetiv, mit Verlaub *eur(er) Ehre(n)*. Natürlich ist *auto* nicht automatisch mit Schnelligkeit konnotiert. Nicht jeder fährt ein schnelles Auto. Mancher fährt 'ne lahme Ente. Kann ja alles sein. Sachen gibts.

Das ist wichtig, weil engl. *connote* auch als Verb begegnet, das irgendwas über die Wahrnehmung des Sprechers aussagen soll, logischer Weise.

Was ich damit meine ist in German Fachtexten ist das Wort ja mit einer gewissen Bedeutung aus der Fachtradition, eh, konnotiert. Da dürfte es beachtliche Unterschiede geben. Müsste man mal nachgoogeln.